# Using queries with ORDER BY when testing with the embedded runtime

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am developing my composer application using TDD approach, so it's important that all the code can run in the embedded runtime used in tests.

My stumbling block is that I cannot make queries using ORDER BY clause to work in tests.

This is a snippet of my model:

```
asset AssetStatement identified by statementRevisionId {
  o String statementRevisionId
  o String statementId
  o DateTime createdAt
  o String effectiveDate regex=/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/
  o Integer revision range=[0,]
  o Boolean actual
  o AssetStatementInfo info
}
```

And this is the query:

```
query FindActualAssetStatement {
  description: "Finds actual asset statement with given (non-unique) id"
  statement:
    SELECT com.assetrisk.AssetStatement
    WHERE (actual == true AND statementId == _$id)
    ORDER BY revision DESC
    LIMIT 1
}
```

If I remove ORDER BY line the query runs, but when it's there I am getting the following exception:

```
Error: Cannot sort on field(s) "revision" when using the default index
 at validateSort (node_modules/pouchdb-find/lib/index.js:472:13)
 at node_modules/pouchdb-find/lib/index.js:1138:5
 at <anonymous>
 at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

The same error happens even if I use asset's unique key field for sorting.

This seems to be a known feature of PouchDB:
https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/6399

However, I don't seem to have access to the underlying database object in the embedded composer environment to configure indices for tests to work.

Is there a way this could be made to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, we bypass this by modifying the test command to comment out the ORDER BY statements before the tests and uncomment them after:

`"test": "sed -i '' -e 's,  ORDER BY,// ORDER BY,g' ./queries.qry && mocha -t 0 --recursive && sed -i '' -e 's,// ORDER BY,  ORDER BY,g' ./queries.qry"`

It is a bit hacky, and does not solve the complex issue of PouchDB not handling indices, but it's probably better than not testing at all.